# Repeating rows and columns in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to make two 600x800 matrices (`X` and `Y`) that look like the following:
- `X` has 0 to 600 in every row
- `Y` has 800 to 0 in every column

My idea was to do something along these lines:

```
N = np.arange(0, 600, 1)  
M = np.arange(0, 800, 1)

X = np.zeros((800, 600))  
Y = np.zeros((800, 600))
```

And from here, put `N` into every row in `X`, and put `M[::-1]` into every column in `Y`, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck as NumPy has a built-in for exactly that task in [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) -

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(N,M[::-1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: N
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [3]: M
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

In [4]: X,Y = np.meshgrid(N,M[::-1])

In [5]: X
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

In [6]: Y
Out[6]: 
array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

Since the question is tagged with [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) too, I would add in another approach using it after initialization with zeros (as listed in the question), like so -

```
m,n = M.size, N.size    # Size parameters

X = np.zeros((m,n),dtype=N.dtype)
Y = np.zeros((m,n),dtype=M.dtype)

X += N
Y += M[::-1,None]
```

Comment: Awesome! That was so much easier than I was expecting.. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielleSkinner Yup, all that in one step! :)